# How can I get black and white text from an image and get geographic coordinates in degrees and convert to decimal geographic coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I would like to extract the coordinates of the following image:
[image]

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
bg = cv2.medianBlur(img, 51)
out = 255 - cv2.absdiff(bg, img)
out = cv2.resize(out, (0, 0), fx=0.8, fy=0.8)
text = pt.image_to_string(out)
print(text)
```

`TNS 4° 39°96.2" N\\n`

[image]

Any idea how I could do it?
I tried with a threshold but I don't think it's the way

[image]

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
thres = cv2.threshold(img,235,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
text = pt.image_to_string(thres )
print(text)
```

`return 'WwW wey 4 FF "WN\n'`
[image]

Comment: The algorithm that does that chooses black or white based on the average background for the digit.  You might try converting all the pure black to pure white, then change everything less than white to black.  That should isolate the digits.

Comment: those digits are either black or white. whatever processing you do that makes them NOT that should NOT be done. you need two threshold operations (one for almost-white, another for almost-black), that you then combine...